# SSL/HTTPS connection establishment slow

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, azure, https, tcp

I have a website on a virtual machine on Microsoft Azure. Since one week ago, I have a lot of new active users (about 5000) and all is really slow now. With the server I have, it should be really fast.
I have audited a little bit and the slow loadings are only when the HTTPS is used :

[image: Google Chrome network console ouput]

Why there is a congestion only on HTTPS ?

Moreover, I used Wireshark to see all the transmission and I saw that there is a TCP retransimition (that I don't have in http) that slow the connection establishement.

[image: WireShark screen]

For the server, I'm using an Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache2.4.

Comment: If you have access to the apache error and access logs, please have a look at them, too (or edit them into your question).

Comment: I'm not that much of a networking guy but so much "tcp retransmission" indicates there is some kind of networking issue, better check that first.

Comment: Did you check available entropy? Slow handshakes in cryptographic protocols are often an indicator for a lack of entropy. If `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` shows some number below thousand install `haveged` to your linux box.